# Servicestack authentication process on each request

Tags: servicestack

I have been through much of the documentation and examples provided, but Im looking for some inputs for my setup from other users.

I have a some clients (website, iOs/Android apps). These only serves as a shelves and its content will be requested through servicestack, which makes servicestack a central point of my setup.
The client will login through servicestack and get a sessionid.

My question here is, how should i setup servicestack to make sure that the user is validated on each request?

I was thinking after login, i save the user in the cache and make sure this expires after some time (unless persisted). Then on each request based on the session id, i check the cache to see if the user exists. If the user exists, the request i authenticated, and if not the user have to login again.

Am i on the right track here, or is there an easier way in servicestack, to support this?

Comment: No one? This is a big architectural issue for me, so any inputs is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have found any solutions ? I have exaclty the same issue. Thanks

Comment: Yes i have something to go on now. When the client logs in through the builtin /auth function i ServiceStack, a AuthUserSession is created and the client recieves the SessionId. This session id is passed to servicestack on every request (eg. as part of the header), and the AuthUserSession is retrieved from Redis based on this session id. The AuthUserSession has the property "IsAuthenticated", which you can use to validate the user.

Answer (score 1):

**I was thinking after login, i save the user in the cache and make sure this expires after some time (unless persisted).**

It sounds like you can just use the [Authentication/Authorization](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization) plugin. Once a user is authenticated (using any of the 'Providers') the user's session is stored in the [cache](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Caching)  using the key 'urn:iauthsession:[sessionId]' and contains a bool property isAuthenticated. For any Service the requires Authentication you can use the [Authenticate attribute](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Authentication-and-authorization#the-authenticate-attribute).