# ServiceStack: Authenticate each request using headers in the HTTP request

Tags: web-services, authentication, servicestack

I have have read [other posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15804582/servicestack-authentication-process-on-each-request) on the same topic, but I haven't really gotten a clear picture of how to best solve this:

I have a webservice, that is "stateless" when it comes to the authentication/session,  meaning that the client will send two strings with every request (in the HTTP header), `AuthToken` and `DeviceUUID`.

These two strings are then compared to the storage, and if found, we know which user it is.

### 1)

Id like to use the `[Authenticate]` attribute for each service that I want to protect, and then a method should be executed where I check the two strings.

### 2)

If I add the `[RequiredRole]`, a method should also be executed, where I have access to the HTTP headers  (the two strings), so I can do my lookup.

I am unsure of how to do this in the easiest and cleanest manner possible. I do not want to create ServiceStack Session objects etc, I just want a method that, for each decorated services, runs a method to check authenticated state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to execute something else **in addition** when the `[Authenticate]` and `[RequiredRole]` attributes are used then it sounds like you want a custom `[MyAuthenticate]` [Request Filter attribute](http://docs.servicestack.net/filter-attributes) which does both, i.e. validates that the request is Authenticated and executes your custom functionality, e.g:

```
public class MyAuthenticateAttribute : AuthenticateAttribute
{
    public override async Task ExecuteAsync(IRequest req, IResponse res, object dto)
    {
        await base.ExecuteAsync(req, res, requestDto);

        var authenticated = !res.IsClosed; 
        if (authenticated)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it instead of `[Authenticate]` in places where you need that extra functionality:

```
[MyAuthenticate]
public class MyServices { ... }
```

But I'd personally keep the logic in the attributes separated:

```
public class MyLogicPostAuthAttribute : RequestFilterAsyncAttribute 
{
    public override async Task ExecuteAsync(IRequest req, IResponse res, object dto)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

So they're explicit and can be layered independently of the `[Authenticate]` attribute, e.g:

```
[Authenticate]
[MyLogicPostAuth]
public class MyServices { ... }
```

Which can also be combined like:

```
[Authenticate, MyLogicPostAuth]
public class MyServices { ... }
```

Comment: Great, thanks! I have to say, ServiceStack is very well constructed and very versatile!